# Break at exception without error information

Tags: objective-c, exception, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This code is breaking for a non-fatal exception, but no significant error information is provided. This is after a core data entity has been updated.

```
-(void) commitBackgroundChangesAndNotify:(NSString *)notification{
    NSLog(@"enter commit");

    if([self.backgroundMOC hasChanges]) {

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (!([self.backgroundMOC save:&error])){     // breaks here
            NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } 

//        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notification object:nil];

    }   

    NSLog(@"exit commit");

}
```

It breaks in the debugger whether I have breakpoints enabled or not. If I run it without the debugger, it appears to run okay.

This code is run several times during an NSOperation. During the operation, the break occurs the second time it is called to save (meaning changes to the context have already been successfully saved once.) I verified that the backgroundMOC was created in the same thread that the changes and the commits are being made, which is the thread of the NSOperation. I also looked at the counts for the moc insertedObjects, updatedObjects, and deletedObjects. These all look right.

The calling code looks like this:

```
- (void) calculateBoundsForSearch {
    NSArray *searchesArray = [currentSearchEntity.resultOfSearch allObjects];

    MyMKMapBounds bounds = [MapController calculateBoundsForArrayOfSearchResults:searchesArray];

    currentSearchEntity.minLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bounds.min.latitude];
    currentSearchEntity.minLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bounds.min.longitude];
    currentSearchEntity.maxLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bounds.max.latitude];
    currentSearchEntity.maxLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:bounds.max.longitude];

    [dataInterface commitBackgroundChangesAndNotify:@"bounds"];
}
```

This is called by two objects. For one, there is no exception.

The only output in the console is this:

```
2012-07-22 10:47:13.790 myApp[46578:17e07] enter commit

Catchpoint 7 (exception thrown).2012-07-22 10:47:21.160 myApp[46578:17e07] exit commit
```

This is a non-fatal exception. One thing I noticed, which I don't understand, is that when it breaks, I have to click continue twice to get past it. The message `Catchpoint 7 (exception thrown).` is shown after the first click.

I'm trying to figure out what tools I have on hand to determine the cause of the exception. Of course, any ideas on what is causing the exception would be helpful, too.

Comment: Are you sure that you use only one managed object context per thread?

Comment: I checked the value of [NSOperationqueue currentQueue] inside this method, and it's the same every time. It's the same as the NSOperation queue.

Comment: Can you show the code of `backgroundMOC save` if it's not too big?

Comment: The line [self.backgroundMOC save:&error] is a method of NSManagedObject. If that's not what you mean, I don't follow you.

Comment: Sorry, I was elsewhere with my thoughts. Do you get an exception with \@try {} \@catch {}?

Comment: Before anything else, you probably already know that 'error' has a property userInfo, which is a dictionary containing much more useful information about what happened. Just loop trough all keys and display values with nslog.

Comment: Yes, but the odd thing about this is that the break occurs before the error is returned (see my code - it breaks at the if-save line), `error` is nil at the time the break occurs.

Comment: Some googling seems to suggest that these Catchpoint thingies are thrown by the Core Data engine when an improper value is set. The most likely candidate is 'MyMKMapBounds bounds' not possessing the values or type of values you think it has, i.e. is 'bounds.min.latitude' really guaranteed to possess a valid float?